# share third-party dependencies between multiple repositories

Tags: gradle

I have multiple java repositories, each with their own libs.version.toml file.
The files have shared third-party dependencies (for e.g. grpc etc).
Today If I need to upgrade the dependencies, I need to make these changes in multiple repositories.
Is there a way where I can declared a shared libs.version.toml that can be used by both multiple repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can share your versions catalog (like `libs.versions.toml`) across repositories. You just publish it as a regular artifact on maven and then consume it in your other builds.

```kotlin
plugins {
    `version-catalog`
    `maven-publish`
}

catalog {
    // declare the aliases, bundles and versions in this block
    versionCatalog {
        library("my-lib", "com.mycompany:mylib:1.2")
    }
}

group = "com.mycompany"
version = "1.0"

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            from(components["versionCatalog"])
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your `settings.gradle.kts` you can import it like this (assuming your catalog project is called `catalog`):

```kotlin
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            from("com.mycompany:catalog:1.0")
        }
    }
}
```

You can read up more on this here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sec:version-catalog-plugin